# Facebook wall post likes are not counted in fql query

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-like, facebook-timeline

I have app which share video on the timeline after uploading on youtube. and we count number of likes whoever likes. The problem is whenever someone likes the video on the personal wall it is not connecting to youtube url.

Timeline post has 13 likes but FQL is showing only 11 excluding share count.

Any help

Answer (score 0):

It seems Facebook does not gives accurate Like results, at first thought it was caused by users privacy settings, but doing some test with my own friends, the API still shows a discrepancy between the like total_count and the amount of like objects returned. It's either a bug or a mysterious deliberated decision by Facebook.

Please check these other people asking something similar:

- [Difference between a post's likes count and the likes data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043467/difference-between-a-posts-likes-count-and-the-likes-data)
- [Facebook Graph API and FQL like count on photo's both incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808391/facebook-graph-api-and-fql-like-count-on-photos-both-incorrect)
- [like table doesn't have all the likes done by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133837/like-table-doesnt-have-all-the-likes-done-by-the-user)