# like table doesn't have all the likes done by the user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am trying to fetch all the likes that a user has done. I am using the following *fql* queries to fetch the likes.

```
SELECT object_type, post_id, object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()
```

I am passing the user's access token along with this query.

Some of the user's like activity is not reflecting in the like table. Did some tests and found out that the missing ones are the likes on posts of some specific friends.

I haven't yet figured out if there are any other like activities of the user that is missing from the like table.

What are the rules by which a like activity of a user is recorded in the like table?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Facebook does not gives accurate Like results, at first thought it was caused by users privacy settings, but doing some test with my own friends, the API still shows a discrepancy between the like total_count and the amount of like objects returned. It's either a bug or a mysterious deliberated decision by Facebook.

Please check these other people asking something similar:

- [Difference between a post's likes count and the likes data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043467/difference-between-a-posts-likes-count-and-the-likes-data)
- [Facebook Graph API and FQL like count on photo's both incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808391/facebook-graph-api-and-fql-like-count-on-photos-both-incorrect)
- [Facebook wall post likes are not counted in fql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342421/facebook-wall-post-likes-are-not-counted-in-fql-query)